# Prove that connection is compatible with the metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I'm trying to show that the connection is compatible with the metric, to do this, I must evaluate

$$
\nabla_{\sigma} g^{\mu \nu} = \partial_{\sigma}g^{\mu \nu} +\Gamma^{\mu}_{\sigma \lambda}g^{\lambda \nu}+\Gamma^{\nu}_{\sigma \lambda}g^{\mu \lambda} = 0.
$$

The space-time I'm considering is the following general static spherically symmetric line element

$$
ds^{2} = -A(r)dt^{2}+B(r)^{-1}+ r^{2}(d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta \ d\phi^{2}) \,\, .
$$

What is my advance until now:

I have to evaluate the christoffel symbols, so I proceed, for example,

$$
\Gamma^{0}_{00} = -\frac{1}{2}A(r)^{-1}(0+0-0) = 0 \,\, ,
$$

My doubt is: Do I need to evaluate all the components of the covariant derivative $\nabla_{\sigma}g^{\mu \nu}$ to the connection be compatible with the metric?

What's the relation between the free indice $\sigma$ of the covariant derivative and the free indice $\lambda$ of the Christoffel symbol? Both range from 0 to 3?

My difficult lies in the evaluation of each component this tensorial equation, once there are lots of indices I get confused, how to perform the evaluation of these components? Could show me the procedure to evaluate at least one component to use as example?

Comment: The expression you have is incorrect.  It should be $\nabla_\sigma g^{\mu \nu} = \partial_\sigma g^{\mu \nu} + \Gamma ^{\mu} {}_{\sigma \lambda} g^{\lambda \nu} + \Gamma ^{\nu} {}_{\sigma \lambda} g^{\mu \lambda}.$

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thank you, I'm gonna update the question, could you make an answer to me using the right expression? I would like to upvote if it's good answer!

Comment: @WaynerKlën I can write up an answer for you but as is your question is incomplete. Do you have a specific metric that you want to take the covariant derivative of? Are you wanting to do this in general? If you have a specific metric, have you already worked out the Christoffel symbols for that metric?

Comment: Hey @Mason, I'm working witha general estacionary spherically symmetric $ds^{2} = -A(r)dt^{2}+B(r)^{-1}dr^{2}+d\Omega^{2} $, where $d\Omega^{2} = r^{2}(d\theta^{2}+\sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2})$. I've worked in Christoffel Symbols but i'm not sure if I have to comput all of they, or just some of they, it's because of the free indices, actually I'm not getting to match the free indices of Christoffel symbols to  that from covariante derivative, does it makes sense to you?

Comment: Yep, I think I understand. I'll write up an answer now. I think you should edit your question so that you either supply the metric you are working with or just say "how do I do this given that I already have the form of the metric and Christoffel Symbols?"

Comment: @WaynerKlën Actually, from your comment I'm not unsure I understood you correctly. Do you know how to calculate the Christoffel symbols? Like if I asked you what $\Gamma^0_{00}$ was, could you calculate it?

Comment: @Mason, I'll Edit my question and supply all your points!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62340/discussion-between-wayner-klen-and-mason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So given a metric and the Christoffel symbols, we want to show that
\begin{equation}
\nabla_\sigma g^{\mu \nu} = \partial_\sigma g^{\mu \nu} + \Gamma^\mu_{\sigma \lambda} g^{\lambda \nu} + \Gamma^\nu_{\sigma \lambda} g^{\mu \lambda} = 0
\end{equation}

First of all, if we want, we can simply our lives here by noticing that $g^{\mu \nu} = g^{\nu \mu}$ and hence we really only need to show that
\begin{equation}
\partial_\sigma g^{\mu \nu} + 2 ~\Gamma^\mu_{\sigma \lambda} g^{\lambda \nu} = 0~~.
\end{equation}

However, I think you probably want more instruction with the index notation so I won't make that simplification.

So let's say you want to calculate the $0,0,0$ component of this tensor, i.e. we set $\sigma = \mu = \nu = 0$ so we have

\begin{equation}
\nabla_0 g^{00} = \partial_0 g^{0} + \Gamma^0_{0 \lambda} g^{\lambda 0} + \Gamma^0_{0 \lambda} g^{0 \lambda}~.
\end{equation}

But now we have two sets of repeated indices so we need to sum over both of them independently so we do it like this
\begin{align}
\nabla_0 g^{00} &= \partial_0 g^{0} + \Gamma^0_{0 0}g^{00} + \Gamma^0_{0 1}g^{10} + \Gamma^0_{0 2}g^{02} + \Gamma^0_{0 3}g^{03} + \Gamma^0_{0 \lambda} g^{0 \lambda}
\end{align}
Now we just have one set of contracted indices so we expand those as well
\begin{align}
\nabla_0 g^{00} = \partial_0 g^{00} + \Gamma^0_{0 0}g^{00} + \Gamma^0_{0 1}g^{10} + \Gamma^0_{0 2}g^{20} + \Gamma^0_{0 3}g^{30} + \Gamma^0_{0 0}g^{00} + \Gamma^0_{0 1}g^{01} + \Gamma^0_{0 2}g^{02} + \Gamma^0_{0 3}g^{03}
\end{align}

Now given all the components of $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ and $\mathbf{g}$ we can plug in the numbers and show that this evaluates (hopefully) to zero! This can now be repeated for every value of $\sigma,~ \mu$ and $\nu$.

I hope this helps, if not or if there's anything else you'd like clarification on please ask!

---

Edit:

I just saw your edit so I'll answer those extra questions here:

> Do I need to evaluate all the components of the covariant derivative [of the metric for] the connection be compatible with the metric?

Yes, I believe so.

> What's the relation between the free indice σ of the covariant derivative and the free indice λ of the Christoffel symbol? Both range from 0 to 3?

The two indices are effectively unrelated. $\lambda$ is a dummy index denoting a dot product between the Christoffel symbol and the (inverse) metric.

Comment: Isn't it missing one more indice in the partial derivative of the metric tensor, i.e, shouldn't it be $\partial_{0}g^{00}$?

Comment: @HerrSchrödinger Yep, you're right. Just a typo! Other than that, does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, It makes sense! By now it's just this! Thanks @Mason!

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your update by the way